# Calculate inductance of a coil with an iron core inside

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, inductance, coil, analysis

I want to calculate inductance of a coil with an iron core inside. The iron core is not vertically centered, but it is still aligned along the axis of the coil.

[image]

I know that FEMM softwares and numerical methods can be used, however I'm wondering how to calculate it analytically.

I'm not asking for the whole calculations, a hint for the procedure of solving it would help me.

Comment: I'm not up on the literature, but I suspect an analytical solution does not exist, or at least not one short enough you'd want to bother with. Well, do you know how to set up the boundary conditions? Identify symmetries to reduce the problem?

Comment: This question is very ambiguous.  Even changing the grade of "iron" can greatly affect the answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams what makes it hard ? no I'm not familiar with how to set boundaries, at first I thought that it might be solved like calculating force on the iron core, if I'm not mistaken that force can be calculated by multiplying a constant with integral of magnetic field over the volume of coil as well as core.

Comment: @rdtsc I would assume the core would have some given isotropic permeability (or perhaps axially-aligned anisotropy, or unaligned, in increasing level of difficulty probably), and coil and core dimensions would all be free variables, perhaps subject to limitations (core strictly inside coil? core strictly to one side?) or approximations (core OD near coil ID? coil ID/OD/length within some ratio?). This is a lot of variables, so, one should expect the corresponding solution to be at least as complex (at least a multivariate rational polynomial).

Comment: Given that the airgap for the entire flux path is still about 50% of that without the core, a reasonable ballpark would be twice the inductance without the core.